# i need to change the affect with css elementor code for a slideing out widget

Tags: css, wordpress, flexbox

this code add transition for css widget bout when it appears to show over the screen with slightly grey affect iam wanting it to not do that what code should i add ?

```
.premium-magic-section-wrap {
    text-align: center;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

[image]

my point is i want the widget to appear with no affect of this gray back ground more like transport to show what behind it